# Specify JsonConverters with attributes in Json.net?

Tags: json.net

I am receiving JSON data to my server with dates represented like this:

```
{
    "startDate": {
        "d": "/Date(1346454000000)/"
    },
    "slots": [
        {
            "d": "/Date(1347058800000)/"
        },
        {
            "d": "/Date(1347145200000)/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Its serialized to a simple object:

```
public class SlotsVm
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime[] Slots { get; set; }
}
```

Because the date format is strange, I had to write a custom JsonConverter to process it. To deserialize, I use code like this:

```
var slotsVm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlotsVm>(body,
    new CustomDateTimeConverter());
```

If possible, I would like the need for the converter to be defined on the `SlotsVm` class, rather than in the code that actually makes the conversion. This is possible for the `startDate` property using attributes:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

but it is not possible for `Slots`, which is an array instead of a simple `DateTime`.

It would be best for me to be able to define the converters that the class needs on the class itself:

```
[JsonConverters(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter), ...]
public class PutDealVm
{

}
```

but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

Can you think of a solution? Is there some way to define converters for a class that I have missed? Alternatively, is it possible to define the converter that an array should user for each of its elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this? I appreciate that this may not directly answer your question, but I was too lazy to recreate the `CustomDateTimeConverter` class, so came up with this instead, which is arguably simpler, as there is no need for a custom converter.

```
string json = "{\"startDate\": {\"d\": \"/Date(1346454000000)/\"},\"slots\": [{\"d\": \"/Date(1347058800000)/\"},{\"d\": \"/Date(1347145200000)/\"}]}";

SlotsVmDeserialized slotsVmDeserialized =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlotsVmDeserialized>(json);

SlotsVm slotsVm = new SlotsVm()
{
    Slots = slotsVmDeserialized.Slots.Select(d => d.Date),
    StartDate = slotsVmDeserialized.StartDate.Date
};

....

public class SlotsVm
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> Slots { get; set; }
}

public class SlotsVmDeserialized
{
    public DateObject StartDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DateObject> Slots { get; set; }
}

public class DateObject
{
    [JsonProperty("d")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

What I've done here is firstly deserialized to the `SlotsVmDeserialized` class, which is used to hold a single `DataObject` and an IEnumerable of them. The `DateObject` class is essentially my alternative/workaround to the custom converter. I could have done all this without any attributes by removing `[JsonProperty("d")]` and renaming `Data` to `D`.

Once deserialized, I then create a new `SlotsVm` object based on the properties of the `SlotsVmDeserialized` object.

Comment: This is a nice trick. It doesn't quite solve the main problem, which is to have the deserialization process fairly transparent to the caller, but I think I can use the idea of a custom `DateObject` class. Thanks.